# Jenkins - Ant Build Maven Deploy

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, ant, nexus

I have a project with a complicated ant build that we would like to remain as ant at the moment (will be converted to maven eventually).

I am using jenkins at the moment to build/test our application. After build/test, I now want to push the built artefact to a Nexus repository.

For a Maven project, I can use the post build action "Deploy Artefacts to Maven Repository" to do this.

Whats the best way to structure my Jenkins jobs to achieve an ant build and then deploy the code to Nexus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the example Ant scripts in the Sonatype website?

They actually include pushing artefacts to Nexus:
http://central.sonatype.org/pages/apache-ant.html#signing-and-deployments-using-the-maven-ant-tasks

Or there is also some more docs at Sonatype:
http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging-deployment.html#staging-ant